# How to return dynamic object from SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

I have situation where a storeprocdure return collection, but I do not how the object structure because the query is very dynamic.

One query can return:

> Id | Location | MarketSegment | ... n columns

and another can return

> Id | Sales Rep | Location | Region | ... n columns

I am simply just return a "object" as you can see in the code below. I know this won't work, but how can I set it up so it does?

```
using (DbContext db = new Context())
{

    var items = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>(
        "SP @Param1, @Param2",
        new SqlParameter("Param1", ped),
        new SqlParameter("Param2", 25)
    ).ToList();

    return Request.CreateResponse<List<object>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
}
```

EDIT:

I don't know if showing the SP will help in anyways, except if I can explain it more.

Each columns are represented as Custom Fields. Users are able to create n numbers of Custom Fields. So If you run the SP for User1 and he has 5 custom fields, then each custom fields will be represented in Columns, but If User2 has 3 custom fields, only 3 columns will be represented. What I don't have control over is the Custom Field Name and number of custom fields.

Comment: Please show us what `SP` is.

Comment: please see edited comment.

Answer (score 10):

If on SQL 2016 or newer, add "FOR JSON AUTO" to your query to return as JSON, e.g:

```
var json = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select x, y, z FROM tbl FOR JSON AUTO").First();
```

Then use Json.Net to create a dynamic object using

```
var myDynamic = JObject.Parse(json)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't use [`SqlQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) for custom fields.

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic
>   type. The type can be any type that has **properties that match the
>   names of the columns** returned from the query, or can be a simple
>   primitive type. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

But, you can use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve that.

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    db.Database.Connection.Open();

    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SP @Param1, @Param2";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Param1", ped));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Param2", 25));

    List<List<object>> items = new List<List<object>>();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var item = new List<Object>();
        items.Add(item);

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount ; i++)
            item.Add(reader[i]);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse<List<object>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you know what all the possible columns could be returned, there is no issue with using a class that has more properties than you need.

```
public class Data
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public string SalesRep {get;set;}//Simply will be empty in the first example, but populated in the second.
public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not true (bitter voice of experience). Doing this will result in
Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in System.Data.dll

If you catch the error and continue, then it will still work, but performance becomes horrible. I have a case where it increases execution from 290 ms to 4 seconds.