# How can I get Entity Framework dynamic query result for web api result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a report viewer as ap.net web api application. SO I need an entity framework dynamic query result.

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> MyQuery()
{
    const string queryString = " SELECT ..... " ; // this is my complex sql query
    var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(queryString).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

My sql query returns any type of object like below:

(Name, Total)

(Name, Total, Category)
(Name, TOtal, CityOnoTotal, CityTwoTotal)

So I want to use this result in my asp.net web api action method. Query runs and 
gets some results.

I used to see response on Postman like this.

[image]

My query response properties are lose.

Comment: Did you tried to send back `object`? (just curious for the result). Maybe it makes sense to revork an `dynamic` to something like `Dictionary<string, object>`?

Comment: No, how can I get dynamic values from in Dictionary? Can u explain more clear wit code?

Comment: @bookmarker did you try to return jsonresult by using Json.Net serialization like JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)

Comment: Yes I used it but sql query result creates empty objects. So the result is like that.

Comment: @bookmarker I searched a bit and it seems you can not use EF SqlQuery with unknown type,  this link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/25497376/8175473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This I suppose wouldn't work, because `EF` is **not returning** properties in the dynamic object **at all**, for explained case.

It works other way around, First `EF` Takes all properties of provided `Generic Type` attribute, Then it tries to map properties to SQL request results.

So if you don't know what is the list of fields will be as result `EF` wouldn't generate it for you.

**First** solution will be to parse select list to define the fields and generate class dynamicaly. Check [how to create dynamic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-dynamically-create-a-class-in-c) discussion. Than you can do something like

```
var dType = MyTypeBuilder.CompileResultType("sample", new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { "Id", typeof(int) }
});
var db = new Model1().Database;
var sql = db.GetType().GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "SqlQuery" && m.IsGenericMethod);
var gen = sql.First().MakeGenericMethod(dType);

var result = gen.Invoke(db, new object[] { "[Your SQL]", new object[0] });
var ie = (result as IEnumerable<object>);
```

that is really complex, but works

**Second** - you can do classic ADO `SQLCommand` using `context.Database.Connection` and parse results

**Third** way to solve the problem is to Return XML from SQL, if possible.

```
var query = db.SqlQuery<string>("[Your SQL] for XML PATH('item'), root('root')").First();
```

that will return all data in XML format Like:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <Id>5</Id>
        ...
    </item>
    <item>
        <Id>6</Id>
        ...
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: So I could parse DataRows to an object as dynamically. But how?

Comment: Or generate class dynamically, or call SQLCmmand via ADO and parse `DataTable`

Comment: check also a possibility to use XML result from SQL

Comment: **Forth:** Return JSON from SQL
 `var query = db.SqlQuery<string>("[Your SQL] for json path").First();`

Comment: @Shady good point. Just don't forget to mention the version, I suppose SQL Server starting with 2016