# Return an unknown object in an ApiController witih EF?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to return a result set from the database without knowing the schema in advanced?

I'm exposing the ability for the client to pass parameters to a stored procedure via API:

```
    [Route("TheRequest")]
    public object Get([FromUri] TheRequest request)
```

This will then return:

```
_repository.Database.SqlQuery<object>(request.ToSqlString());   //execute sql against a stored procedure, passing in the required parameters to it
```

When attempting to do this, I believe that the controller doesn't know how to serialize the object returned. This is what postman returns:

[image]

Is it possible to return a Json serialized object response from the database without knowing the object schema?

Comment: Could you please show more code, especially, how do you return.

Comment: Why can't you just pass the object to the seralizer and return a jsonContentResult

Comment: @johnny5 could you give me an example?

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj) then just return content result. See this msdn for [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: But more general architecture question, Why are you using EntityFramework and write a generic method that returns your expected type.  That way you know what you are returning in the first place

Comment: From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx): *The type can be any type that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query*. `object` is is unlikely to have any properties that match the columns, so your object is empty - I doubt it's a serialization issue...

Comment: I think @Kirk is right, you need to get the dataset instead of trying to convert it to an object, and serialize the dataset instead

Comment: @Kirk i created an object with all fields returned, and typed them to be string, then got conversion issues cannot convert from decimal to string, cannot convert from nullable int to string, etc

Comment: So don’t type them all as string then... Follow the error messages and set the types on your class accordingly.

Comment: @Kirk i was just wondering if that would contradict the docs, the fact that you cannot convert an int to a string?

Comment: When the docs talk of a type, they refer to the generic type used in SqlQuery. Basically just saying it can be a class, struct, etc. It’s not referring to the types of the properties on said type - *they* still need to match the column types, as you’ve discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to return a result set from the database without knowing the schema in advanced?

In regards to *just EF*, the answer is *not really*.  EF was designed for you to know the schema in advance.  So you can still use DAO off of the `ContextDb.Database` but there isn't much point to using EF you you do that.

Now if the question was, *can I generically typed instance from EF* then sure, no problem:

```
var result = DbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault();
```

This code doesn't know what it's pulling at compile time.

> Is it possible to return a Json serialized object response from the database without knowing the object schema?

*Sorta*, as I mentioned before, you can't use EF as it was intended, but you could certainly do something like

```
public ActionResult Index(string type)
{
  var entityType = Type.GetType(type);
  // reflection
  var methods = typeof(ContextDb).GetMethods("Set");

  // Not tested, but something like the following
  // Find the Generic Version
  var method = methods.Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod).FirstOrDefault();
  // Make the method info for the typed method
  var methodInfo = method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
  // Invoke method, cast as needed, get value
  var result = (methodInfo.Invoke(ContextDb) as DbSet).FirstOrDefault();

  return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something in the OP's question, I think he know's what stored procedure he wants to call.  Can you just convert the object to json and be done with it

Comment: If he decides to use a sproc, again there is no point using EF really.  Most of this is regarding EF.  If you want to give an alternative answer using sproc without EF that's totally a good answer.

Comment: yeah, but isn't the issue he's having is that when he calls `.SqlQuery<object>` , he's mapping his results set to a generic object with out all of the properties that he needs, so that when he goes to serialize he's really serializing an empty object.  When in reality he needs to be serializing his dataset

Comment: [Thats my point, EF was not designed to materialize dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494384/how-to-return-dynamic-object-from-sql-query).  Since the question is regarding EF, I'm just saying EF was not designed to accomplish his needs.