# Is there a simpler way to query from MySQL in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Currently to query my table of users I have to do the following in my controller.

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test_schema"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users", connection);
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    List<string> users = new List<string>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
       users.Add(reader["id"] + "\t" + reader["first_name"]);
    }

    ViewBag.users = users;
    reader.Close();
}
```

Is it possible in C# to put the results in a dynamic object similar to how `ViewBag` works?
I have some experience in Node.js Express and to write a query using the `sequelize` module all I have to do is write something like

```
Sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM users", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(users => {
    // users attributes will be the columns of the user table
});
```

I left out the part of how to connect to a database in sequelize but I don't think it is relevant to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dynamic object from SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494384/how-to-return-dynamic-object-from-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done very easily with [Dapper](https://stackexchange.github.io/Dapper/). It supports deserialising data rows to regular C# classes or `dynamic` objects.

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test_schema"].ConnectionString))
{
    // the 'Query' method is provided by Dapper
    var users = connection.Query("SELECT id, first_name FROM users");
    // each object in 'users' will have .id and .first_name properties
    ViewBag.users = users;


    // to duplicate your sample code's behaviour of creating strings:
    var users = connection.Query("SELECT id, first_name FROM users")
        .Select(x => string.Concat(x.id, "\t", x.first_name))
        .ToList();
}
```

Alternatively, you can deserialise to an already-defined type:

```
class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

// here I use 'as FirstName' to change the retrieved column name so I
// can use "normal" C# property names on my User class
var users = connection.Query<User>("select id, first_name as FirstName from users");
```